# Add widgets to jquery Masonry

Tags: jquery

I am a complete newbie to this, but for my site, which is using jquery Masonry, I would like to add 'widgets' (a small 222px x 50px box saying Add us on Facebook etc) to be seen on every page on a solid place, i.e. after the first 5 posts etc.

How can this be done?

P.S.: An example can be seen here: http://www.dazeddigital.com In between the posts, there are widgets like "Read all about it" etc.

Comment: By "In a solid place" you mean "in a fixed position?"